# Remove childrens and items via Observer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2, magento-2.1.7

I have updated the checkout_index_index handle via observer. Now I want to remove the "progress Bar", "Shipping Address", "shipping methods" via observer. So I have tried the below event.

```
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="NameSpace\Module\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
```

LayoutLoadBefore:

```
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
           $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('checkout_index_index'); 
           $layout->unsetElement('checkout_onepage_shippingmethod');
           $layout->unsetElement('checkout_onepage_progress');
           //$layout->unsetBlock('shipping-step');
           $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" display="false"/>'); 
           //$layout->unsetChild('checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress');
           return $this;
    }
```

Still the child elements like "Progress Bar", "Shipping address was not removed". Is there any way to remove this via Event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amit mentioned, checkout blocks are not regular Magento blocks but Ui Components so the way to remove them is different.

The easiest way would be to use a **layout** xml file, so removing the "progress bar" for example would look something like this:

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="progressBar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I don't think there's a way to achieve the same thing using event observers but, if you want to try a similar approach you can use [plugins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) instead, you can hook into the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface::progress` method (which is the one that processes the blocks that make up the checkout page) and remove the blocks you don't need:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface">
        <plugin name="vendor_removecheckoutblocks" type="Vendor\RemoveCheckoutBlocks\Plugin\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/RemoveCheckoutBlocks/Plugin/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\RemoveCheckoutBlocks\Plugin;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    function afterProcess($subject, $result)
    {
        // Remove progress bar
        unset($result['components']['checkout']['children']['progressBar']);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are following Magento 1 process to change the checkout page. But Magento 2 **checkout steps are totally different**. In this version Magento use  **knockout js, jQuery UI element, rest API, local storage**.

Magento 2 version steps are not manege from layout, it use  **knockout js, jQuery UI element, rest API, local storage**.

If you want to do customization at Magento , then please follow  Magento  [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html)